# Pass a function as an another function argument

Tags: r, function

I have two functions, as for example:

```
a <- function(x) return(mean(x))
b <- function(x) return(median(x))
```

I would like to have another function that passes either `a` or `b`  as an argument.

The goal is something like this:

```
oper <- function(f, x) {
  ifelse(f == "a",  a(x), b(x))
}
```

If for example I was to execute the function:

```
oper(a, c(3,4,5))
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in f == "a" : 
comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

Disclosure: mean(x) and median(x) are just for example purposes.

Comment: The `oper()` function works. What is the challenge that you're facing?

Comment: I get this error when executing `oper()`: Error in f == "a" : 
comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types

Comment: With your updated post, I see the error in your command. It should be `oper("a", c(3,4,5))`, where `a` is surrounded by quotation marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because R has [first-class functions](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/fp.html#functional-programming-languages), you can simply pass your function and call it directly:

```
oper2 <- function(f, x) {
  f(x)
}

x <- c(2, 3, 8)

oper2(a, x)
# 4.333333

oper2(b, x)
# 3
```